# TravisCI integration with SonarQube results in Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, sonar-runner

I am running a small project in NodeJS. I am using TravisCI to help with continuos integration. As part of continuous integration, I wanted to integrate with sonarqube to analyze the code.

This is the travis.yml

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6"  
addons:
  sonarqube: true
env:
  SONAR_TOKEN: b9a731b8b00b0cff2299cc21b103855570522cea 
script:
  # other script steps might be done before running the actual SonarQube analysis
  - sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=b9a731b8b00b0cff2299cc21b103855570522cea
```

This is the sonarqube properties file:

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=sheidaei:coffeeclub
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=Coffee Club
sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# Since SonarQube 4.2, this property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
# If not set, SonarQube starts looking for source code from the directory containing 
# the sonar-project.properties file.
sonar.sources=.
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

You can find the whole source of the project on github @ https://github.com/sheidaei/coffeeclub

After automatic builds in TravisCI, I always get an error with sonarqube. It is telling me that it has something to do with major.minor version. I don't know how to fix this issue and how to force a version of java for either travisci or sonarqube. Any thoughts / help appreciated.

```
Preparing SonarQube Scanner CLI
Archive:  /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner.zip
   creating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner.bat  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner-debug  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/lib/sonar-scanner-cli-2.8.jar  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/conf/sonar-scanner.properties  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-runner.bat  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-runner  
  inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8/bin/sonar-scanner-debug.bat  
$ export SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=$HOME/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-2.8
sonarqube.run
Preparing SonarQube Scanner parameters
0.22s$ sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=b9a731b8b00b0cff2299cc21b103855570522cea
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
The command "sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=b9a731b8b00b0cff2299cc21b103855570522cea" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Comment: You must use Java 8.   Upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You must upgrade to Java 8.   See http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-ecosystem-upgrades-to-java-8/

(Alternatively, as the docs indicate you may use a previous, Java 7 compatible version of SQ.)

Comment: I am using sonarqube.com to run the sonar analysis. Is there an option to upgrade there? Any thoughts?